# Get text of children in a div with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Hi i want the description of an App in the Google Playstore. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wetter.androidclient&hl=de)

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wetter.androidclient&hl=de"))
result = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"show-more-content text-body"})
```

With this code i get the whole content in this class. But i can't get only the text in it. I tried a lot of things with next_silbing or .text but it always throws errors(ResultSet has no attribute xxx).

I just want to get the text like this: "Die Android App von wetter.com! Sie erhalten: ..:"

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 39):

Use the `.text` attribute on the elements; you have a *list* of results, so loop:

```
for res in result:
    print(res.text)
```

`.text` is a property that proxies for the [`Element.get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

Alternatively, if there is only ever supposed to be *one* such `<div>`, use `.find()` instead of `.find_all()`:

```
result = soup.find("div", {"class":"show-more-content text-body"})
print(result.text)
```

Comment: Note that according to the documentation, that property does not exist. However, the [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function does.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that’s a documentation bug. `.text` is a [property that calls `.get_text()`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/614/bs4/element.py#L296).

Comment: hm, I don't see a bug for that over on https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/, and it's a pretty well written section so... if it is, it might still be good to talk about `get_text()` as "the thing" and `.text` as a convenient shortcut to it - if folks want to find out more about this property, they're not going to find it in the docs by searching for `.text`, whereas they _are_ going to find things by searching for `get_text`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: fair enough, added.

Answer (score 2):

Use `decode_contents()` method.

```py
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wetter.androidclient&hl=de"))
result = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"show-more-content text-body"})

for res in result:
    print(res.decode_contents().strip())
```

You'll get the innerHTML from div.

Answer (score 1):

If wanting to extract text from all elements into a list, a list comprehension can come in handy:

```py
texts = [r.text.strip() for r in results]
```