# Printing contents from class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to print the text inside the class.

This is the HTML snip(It is inside of many classes, But in visual, It is next to Prestige->

```
<div class="sc-ikPAkQ ceimHt">
   9882
</div>
```

THis is my code->

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://auntm.ai/champions/abomination/tier/6"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for data in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "sc-ikPAkQ ceimHt"}):
    print(data)
```

I want to print the integer 9882 from the class
I tried but I failed.
How do I do so?

Comment: Use selenium to scrape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike a typical static webpage, the main content of the webpage is loaded dynamically with JavaScript.

That is, the response body (`page.content`) won't contain all the content you see finally. Instead, upon you accessing the webpage via a Web browser, the browser executing these JavaScript codes which then updates the HTML with data from other data sources (typically, via another API calling or just some hardcoded data in the script itself). In other words, the final HTML shown in the DOM inspector in a Web browser is different from what you gain with `requests.get`. (You can verify this by printing `page.content` or clicking the "View Page Source" entry in the right-click menu on the page).

General ways to handle this case are either:

1. Turn to selenium for help. Selenium is essentially a programmatically controlled Web browser (but without a real window) for JS codes to execute and render the webpage as normal.
2. Inspect JS codes and/or additional network requests on that page to extract the data source. It requires some experience and knowledge with Web dev or JS.

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text by calling `.get("text")` i.e

```py
for data in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "sc-ikPAkQ ceimHt"}):
    data.get("text")
```

Check [getText() vs text() vs get_text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093875/gettext-vs-text-vs-get-text) for different ways of getting the text (and [Get text of children in a div with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889790/get-text-of-children-in-a-div-with-beautifulsoup) for answer to your question)

Comment: It didn't worked. Are you sure text will be in colons?

Comment: you can also just call `data.text` (but it does the same). Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889790/get-text-of-children-in-a-div-with-beautifulsoup and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093875/gettext-vs-text-vs-get-text SO posts. If it does not work, make sure that you are calling it correctly i.e you might need to loop over `data` aswell, if that returns a list etc.

Comment: I am doing this - `for data in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "sc-ikPAkQ ceimHt"}):
    print(data.text)`

Comment: I just tried - your `findAll` returns an empty list: `div = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "sc-ikPAkQ ceimHt"}) #returns []`

Comment: Yeah, for me too. Idk why. In the html it contains text

Comment: You are not certain to get all the data when using request if the webpage uses e.g javaScript to render the page. That might be why, as @Dummmy just explains

Comment: Got it, Thanks for helping me out!